# How a browser isolation product is safer than our enterprise-hardened Chrome?

Tags: chrome, virtualization, safe-browsing-filter

We have been offered a security product that provides browser isolation but I am not really sure what the benefits could be of such a solution in an enterprise.

Comment: It is going to be difficult to answer without knowing what the product does and how you hardened your Chrome. Isn't this a question for the vendor?

Comment: Like, does your set up offer the basics of browser isolation as described in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_isolation ?

Comment: They are being very vague and I was just confused on the concept benefits vs chrome browser best practices harden guidelines we used.

Comment: Then I think your answer is found in the wiki on the topic.

Comment: Yes, just trying to understand the trade-offs of using browser isolation since this itself can expose us to new risks we not aware of.

Comment: Will delete the question.